# Debug infinite loop with io.js and gdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, gdb

I have an application that goes out and crawls a bunch of URLs. Sometimes it will randomly lock up with 100% CPU usage. Whatever is happening leaves it in a state where it never returns to the event loop since I lose the ability to do anything with node-inspector, my logstash events stop being fired off, strace shows me no further system calls, etc.

I was hoping to attach GDB and see if I could get some sort of insight that way. I found a post by Remy Sharp where he was able to do this with node here: https://remysharp.com/2013/09/11/how-i-fixed-an-anonymous-infinite-loop-in-jsbin. Unfortunately things have changed with the newer V8 that io.js uses. I found that when I followed his example I got stuck at the point where he runs `print 'v8::V8::TerminateExecution'(0)`. V8 apparently removed the `TerminateExecution` function from the API (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19408894/918195). Being inexperienced with GDB I fumbled around trying to call `v8::V8::TerminateExecution(v8::Isolate*)` as mentioned in that post to no avail.

At this point I feel like I will have to go down the rabbit hole digging through the V8 source to gain an understanding of how that works in order to just use GDB in troubleshooting this problem. I'm hoping to avoid that if possible.

Any suggestions on how to use GDB with io.js or another way to go about finding the code that is causing my processes to hang at 100% CPU (I'm guessing some infinite loop condition - possibly in a 3rd party library I'm using)?